# How i can do my component in React.js have a individual behavior?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, react-fullstack

I'm implementing a Like and Dislike Button, and I wanna that when I click them will be with other colors, but just the clicked component, when I click all buttons change the state, can anybody help me?

`

```
const indexPost = async () => {
        const data = await api.get('/api/posts')
        if(data.data.length !=0){
            const dataArray = data.data
            if(dataArray.length === 0) {
                return
            }else{
                return(
                    setPost(dataArray.map( data => (
                        <Post key={data._id} id={data._id} title={data.title} text={data.text}>
                            <Like id={data._id}></Like>
                        </Post>
                        
                    )))
               )
         }
     }
           
} 




export default function Like({itemId}) {
    const context = useContext(notificationContext)
    const {isLoved, Like, Loved, Unlike, isLike, isUnlike, setIsLike, setIsUnlike, setIsLoved } = context
    return(
                <div className={styles.likeContainer} key={itemId}>
                            {isLike ? (
                            <button className={styles.likeContent} onClick={() => setIsLike(false)}><Icon.ThumbsUp className={styles.Icon} fill="#5CB0BB" ></Icon.ThumbsUp></button>) : 
                            (<button className={styles.likeContent} onClick={() => Like() }><Icon.ThumbsUp className={styles.Icon}  ></Icon.ThumbsUp></button>)}
                            {isLoved ? 
                            (<button className={styles.likeContent} onClick={() => setIsLoved(false)}><Icon.Heart className={styles.Icon}   fill="red" ></Icon.Heart> </button>) : 
                            (<button className={styles.likeContent} onClick={() => Loved() }><Icon.Heart className={styles.Icon}  ></Icon.Heart></button>)}
                            {isUnlike ? (
                            <button className={styles.likeContent} onClick={() => setIsUnlike(false)}><Icon.ThumbsDown className={styles.Icon}  fill="#702BA6"  ></Icon.ThumbsDown> </button>) : 
                            (<button className={styles.likeContent} onClick={() => Unlike()}><Icon.ThumbsDown className={styles.Icon}  ></Icon.ThumbsDown></button>
                            )}
                     </div>                
    )
};
```

Comment: Did you solved the issue ?

Comment: No, Im still trying.

Comment: okay, i will post the answer

Comment: So Im Still trying to resolve that but looks so hard to me, i cant get the like component individually, when i cliked in the buttons them change the color of all "like" components

Comment: Mat where are you saving the state of the likes  in api , are you updating api ?

Comment: Im not saving the state in the api, Im manipulating the data states in the front-end.

Comment: You are using context to save stuff ?

Comment: basically, when i click in the button like, I change the state to true, and I render a other button to change to false, basically is that

Comment: Yeah im Using the useContext to save this states.

Comment: got it but you have implemented it the wrong way the component structure , I will write a codesandbox implementing similar

Comment: Pls help me.... its very important to me this project and i tried so many ways to resolve but im not getting.

Comment: Sure , give me half an hour , I will do it and share the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onClick() on each like button and attach it with a function, then you can get the value of that particular like with e.currentTarget.id and change its css/style the way you want.

```
const handleClick=(e)=>
    {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
    }
```

Comment: Im still trying fo resolve that but I dont know how to use the currentTarget to get the button individually

Comment: You can use currentTarget to identify which button was clicked ,since each post will have its own id, you can use same id inside button or like icon, so whenever someone will click like, handleClick will be called with **e** as parameter to the function now try to console e.currentTarget.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the similar one in my project, it is very basic , it shows how to update the likes , you need to handle the cases of user authentication and stuff

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect, createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { updateArrayOfObj } from "./utils";
import AllPosts from "./AllPosts";
export const PostsContext = createContext();

const initialState = {
  posts: [
    {
      _id: "1",
      name: "Browny",
      image: "http://placekitten.com/200/310",
      likes: 0,
      love: 0,
      dislikes: 0
    },
    {
      _id: "2",
      name: "Blacky",
      image: "http://placekitten.com/200/320",
      likes: 0,
      love: 0,
      dislikes: 0
    },
    {
      _id: "3",
      name: "SnowWhite",
      image: "http://placekitten.com/200/300",
      likes: 0,
      love: 0,
      dislikes: 0
    }
  ]
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_POST":
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: updateArrayOfObj(
          state.posts,
          action.payload.obj,
          "_id",
          action.payload._id
        )
      };
    case "CREATE_POST":
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts, ...action.payload.data]
      };
    case "DELETE_POST":
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.filter((ele) => ele._id !== action.payload._id)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <PostsContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        dispatch
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <AllPosts />
      </div>
    </PostsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

PostsAll.js

```
import Post from "./Post";
import { PostsContext } from "./App";
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function AllPosts() {
  const { state } = useContext(PostsContext);
  return (
    <div className="allPosts">
      {state.posts.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Post
            name={item.name}
            image={item.image}
            likes={item.likes}
            love={item.love}
            dislikes={item.dislikes}
            id={item._id}
            key={item._id}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Post.js

```
import { PostsContext } from "./App";
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function Post(props) {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(PostsContext);
  const handleUserInteraction = (type, id) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_POST",
      payload: {
        obj: { [type]: props[type] + 1 },
        _id: id
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <h3>{props.name}</h3>
      <img src={props.image} alt="cat" />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => handleUserInteraction("likes", props.id)}>
        {props.likes} Like
      </button>{" "}
      <button onClick={() => handleUserInteraction("love", props.id)}>
        {props.love} Love
      </button>{" "}
      <button onClick={() => handleUserInteraction("dislikes", props.id)}>
        {props.dislikes} Dislike
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can refer to this codesandbox to implement the same

[image: Edit nervous-wing-6f3nd]

Comment: Thank you so much man, i saw now that my problem really was the used of the Context Api, I shared  useless states for whole my application, like the states of buttons, that is restricts states just for the buttons in the Like component, so Thank you so much, i really i implemented the wrong way the component.